# From spreadsheet to dictionary in ipython/python & more?

Tags: python, dictionary, ipython

I would like to be able to take data from a file (spreadsheet or other) and create a dictionary that I can then iterate over in a loop for the keys, and have corresponding values inserted in my command for each key.  Sorry if that does not make much sense, I will explain in more detail below.

I have several samples that I am running through a bioinformatics pipeline and I am trying to automate the process.  One of the steps is adding "read group" information to my files which is done with the following shell command:

> picard-tools AddOrReplaceReadGroups I=input.bam O=output.bam RGID=IDXX
>   RGLB=LBXX RGPL=PLXX RGPU=PUXX RGSM=SMXX VALIDATION_STRINGENCY=SILENT
>   SORT_ORDER=coordinate CREATE_INDEX=true

For each sample ID there is a different RGID, RGLB, GRPL, RGPU, and RGSM (and different input files, but I already know how to call that info.)  What I would like to do is have a loop that executes this command for each sample ID and have the corresponding RGLB, GRPL, RGPU, and RGSM inserted into the command. Is there an easy way to do this? I have been reading a bit and it seems like a dictionary is probably the way to go, but it is not clear to me how to generate the dictionary and call the independent values into my command.

Comment: Can you give us a line or two from the spreadsheet to look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be pretty easy, but how you do it depends on the format of your input file. You're going to want something basically like this:

```
import subprocess # This is how we're going to call the commands.

samples = {} # Empty dict
with open('inputfile','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # Extract sampleID, other things depending on file format...

        samples[sampleID] = [rgid, rglb, grpl, rgpu, rgsm] # Populate dict

for sampleID in samples:
    rgid, rglb, grpl, rgpu, rgsm = samples[sampleID]

    # Now you can run your commands using the subprocess module.
    # Remember to add a change based on sampleID if e.g. the IO files differ.
    subprocess.call(['picard-tools', 'AddOrReplaceReadGroups', 'I=input.bam', 
        'O=output.bam', 'RGID=%s' % rgid, 'RGLB=%s' % rglb, 'RGPL=%s' %rgpl,
        'RGPU=%s' % rgpu, 'RGSM=%s' % rgsm, 'VALIDATION_STRINGENCY=SILENT', 
        'SORT_ORDER=coordinate', 'CREATE_INDEX=true'])
```